# Request Double Type Feature from Geoserver in JavaScript

Tags: postgis, geoserver, javascript, openlayers, pgrouting

I have set up an application according to this [workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/index.html) (using postgis, pgrouting, geoserver, openlayers 3). In order to get a value for the total cost of each route selected I altered the SQL View in Geoserver in step 9 to:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(route.geom), sum(route.cost) AS totalcost
FROM (
    SELECT geom, cost 
    FROM pgr_leastenergy_rec('ways', %x1%, %y1%, %x2%, %y2%) 
    ORDER BY seq
        ) AS route
```

Everything worked out fine - I got this result in Geoserver:

[image]

Since the geometry is already implemented in the routing interface of the next step, I wanted to add the cost factor as well - as an output right under the map. I already tried a few things, unfortunately I am quiet new especially to Javascript. The viewparams variable and the attached request must be altered somehow. Any idea how to achieve that goal?

Comment: do you want the sum of the costs for the route? or just the value totalcost for the line you clicked on?

Comment: Thank you for dealing with that problem! If I had adapted the existing query correctly it should return the sum of the costs for the route requested (accumulating the costs of each edge and returning it as a value for totalcost). But I see what you mean, it probably does not work like this.

Comment: Pardon me, I got confused. The above query should work as long as the st_makeline() returns a table with just one row which I am not able to verify - otherwise it should be possible to remove the sum() and to sum up the costs later on (through Javascript). Do you have any suggestions how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The pgRouting workshop shows the routing result as a WMS layer in OpenLayers, which does not display any other attributes.

An easy modification would be to change the styling in Geoserver and show the total cost attribute as a label rendered together with the route.

A bit more work would be to change the OpenLayers part from WMS to WFS layer. You would then also retrieve the feature properties together with the routing geometry, such as in the following example: http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&outputformat=application/json